# Query Where & Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, average, where-clause

```
WITH AGE_2020 AS
(
    SELECT 
        2020 - YEAR(DATE_DE_NAISSANCE) AS AGE, 
        DATE_DE_NAISSANCE, DEPARTEMENT_CODE
    FROM 
        ELUS
    INNER JOIN 
        VILLES ON ELUS.CODE_INSEE = VILLES.CODE_INSEE
)
SELECT 
    AVG(AGE) AGE_MOYEN,
    DEPARTEMENT_CODE
FROM
    AGE_2020
WHERE 
    AVG(AGE) > 54 
GROUP BY 
    DEPARTEMENT_CODE
ORDER BY 
    AGE_MOYEN;
```

I need to group by department where age > 54 
but that means a error form group by, that work without the clause where
how I can solve this ?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I think you want that to be `HAVING AVG(AGE) > 54` since it's a summary measure.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use having, when using a aggregation in you filtering, go with having instead of group by

```
WITH AGE_2020 AS
(
    SELECT 
        2020 - YEAR(DATE_DE_NAISSANCE) AS AGE, 
        DATE_DE_NAISSANCE, DEPARTEMENT_CODE
    FROM 
        ELUS
    INNER JOIN 
        VILLES ON ELUS.CODE_INSEE = VILLES.CODE_INSEE
)
SELECT 
    AVG(AGE) AGE_MOYEN,
    DEPARTEMENT_CODE
FROM
    AGE_2020

GROUP BY 
    DEPARTEMENT_CODE
HAVING
    AVG(AGE) > 54 
ORDER BY 
    AGE_MOYEN;
```

Comment: @anom This is correct. Remember, "where" is for rows, "having" is for groups.